# записать новые данные в БД

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть два sql файла, некоторые записи в них повторяются, как закинуть в БД эти файлы что бы не продублировать записи?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, проще всего — загрузить их в две временные базы данных, а затем отобрать в нужные таблицы нужную информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в данных есть уникальный набор вроде username/email или что-то, что подходит под уникальность, то импортировать такие данные просто - проставить флаг unique и в запросе писать INSERT IGNORE (или REPLACE) в базе и ничего не продублируется. В остальном все зависит от вашего набора данных. Что в них входит?

Comment: это дампы БД geoip, там каждый start_ip уникальный, вот через импортирование одно да другое не получается

Comment: Как минимум не достаточно информации, чтобы понять чем тот же вариант с INSERT IGNORE не подходит?

Comment: подходит, только дело в том что у меня 86 тыс записей, разбиты на кучу INSERT INTO, и каждому добавлять IGNORE это ежика родить можно

Comment: Ну так для этого есть всякие текстовые тулзы: например notepad++, @textReplace. Одна минута дел. :)